# SSH tunnel freezes and says "administratively prohibited" when a domain cannot be resolved

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

So I am opening a SSH tunnel to a remote server to use it as proxy:

```
ssh -D 10000 -N remote
```

I use FireFox with FoxyProxy and it is working quite well. Except sometimes the tunnel freezes. A good example is the page of [this Australian songwriter](http://johnbutlertrio.com/). The site makes requests to the domain johnbutler-trio.com which might not be configured correctly. The result is that the tunnel freezes for a minute and no further connection is possible until a time out is triggered. After that everything is back to normal until I visit this site again. With the debug switch enabled the output is the following:

```
debug1: channel 5: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 10000 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
...
debug1: Connection to port 10000 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 45: new [dynamic-tcpip]

channel 38: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
debug1: channel 38: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 10000 for johnbutler-trio.com port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 45057 to 127.0.0.1 port 10000, nchannels 46
channel 39: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 40: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 41: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 42: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 43: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
debug1: channel 39: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 10000 for johnbutler-trio.com port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 45058 to 127.0.0.1 port 10000, nchannels 45
debug1: channel 40: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 10000 for johnbutler-trio.com port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 45059 to 127.0.0.1 port 10000, nchannels 44
debug1: channel 41: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 10000 for johnbutler-trio.com port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 45060 to 127.0.0.1 port 10000, nchannels 43
debug1: channel 42: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 10000 for johnbutler-trio.com port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 45061 to 127.0.0.1 port 10000, nchannels 42
debug1: channel 43: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 10000 for johnbutler-trio.com port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 45062 to 127.0.0.1 port 10000, nchannels 41
```

What is going on? How can I prevent the tunnel from freezing when there is an error which somebody's domain? Btw opening random non registered domains won't result in a tunnel freeze.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open